# Typescript: undefined is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have a clone function that I'm testing with Mocha/Chai:

```
export function clone(source: any): any {
    let output = {};
    if (isObject(source)) {
        (<any>Object).keys(source).forEach(key => {
            (<any>Object).assign(output, { [key]: source[key] });
        });
    }
    return output;
}
```

Here's the test:

```
let obj = {
    a: [
        {
            a: 3,
            b: 5,
            c: [6, 8]
        }
    ]
};

it('clone(object) creates deep clone', () => {
    let cloned = ObjectHelper.clone(obj);

    expect(cloned.a[0].a).to.equal(3);
    expect(cloned.a[0].c[1]).to.equal(6);
});
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign(output, (_a = {}, _a[key] = source[key], _a))')
```

This only fails in the tests, not in the browser.

Karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        /*
         * Enable or disable watching files and executing the tests whenever
         * one of the files in the 'files' field is changed.
         */
        autoWatch: true,

        /*
         * The root path location that will be used to resolve all relative
         * paths defined in 'files' and 'exclude'.
         */
        basePath: '',

        /*
         * List of browsers to launch and capture tests in. In order to use a
         * specified browser, you must npm install the corresponding
         * karma-***-launcher.
         * http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/browsers.html
         */
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        // Enable or disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // List of files/patterns to exclude from loaded files
        exclude: [],

        /*
         * The files array determines which files are included in the browser
         * and which files are watched and served by Karma. The order of patterns
         * determines the order in which files are included in the browser.
         * http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html
         */
        files: [
            'src/**/*.spec.ts'
        ],

        /*
         * List of test frameworks you want to use. For example, if you want to
         * use mocha, chai, and sinon, you'll need to npm install their
         * corresponding karma-*** modules and include them in the list of plugins
         * as well as below.
         */
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        /*
         * By default, Karma loads all sibling NPM modules which have a name
         * starting with karma-*. You can also explicitly list plugins you want
         * to load via the plugins configuration setting.
         */
        plugins: [
            'karma-*'
        ],

        // The port where the Karma web server will be listening.
        port: 9876,

        /*
         * A map of preprocessors to use. Requires the corresponding karma-*
         * npm module to be npm installed and added to the 'plugins' field.
         */
        preprocessors: {
            'src/**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack']
        },

        /*
         * A list of reporters to use to display the test results. In order to
         * use the karma-mocha-reporter, you must npm install the module and
         * include it in the list of plugins.
         */
        reporters: ['mocha'],

        /*
         * If true, Karma will start and capture all configured browsers, run
         * tests and then exit with an exit code of 0 or 1 depending on whether
         * all tests passed or any tests failed.
         */
        singleRun: false,

        /*
         * This field is necessary because we are using webpack as a preprocessor.
         * You will need to specify the webpack configuration (although in this
         * case, we are simply leveraging the existing webpack.config.js file).
         *
         * If you have a different webpack.config.js file that's used for testing
         * purposes, you can specify that here.
         */
        webpack: {
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            resolve: webpackConfig.resolve
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you please supply the `obj` that you test with?

Comment: @NitzanTomer thanks, I've added it to the test code block. It fails on the first evaluation of `Object.assign()`

Comment: How are you running the tests? In browser or in another way?

Comment: I'm running them with Karma and PhantomJS - just adding karma conf to post.

Comment: Your types are bad, clone should take a `T` and return a `T` if it indeed clones, and should also respect the prototype chain.

Comment: As in: `let output = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source))`, also you don't handle the case the source isn't an object in which case you want to return the same value immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that your environment does not have `Object.create` implemented, that is you don't have `ES6` features.

Here's a polyfil for PhantomJs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill-object-assign

Also, you can polyfil it in typescript (just so you won't have to cast it to `any`):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    keys(o: any): string[];
    assign(target: any, ...sources: any[]): any;
}
```

If you use `ES6` as the target for your compiler then you won't need this polyfil as it's already built in.